# Corona SDK detect object removal

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is there a way to detect that the displayed object is being removed? Something like:

```
obj:addEventListeren("before_remove", function(ev)
    -- ev.target will be removed soon
end);
```

Comment: Do you want to detect before the object is being removed (as in your example) or you just want to know if a object does not exist anymore?

Comment: Ideally I would like to have callback before object is removed, but checking if object does not exist anymore will do too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to check for the existence of an object before removing it? Then you can check for any of the major properties of that object with `nil`. Like below:

```
local rect = display.newRect(50,50,100,50)  -- Creating an object

local function myFunction(e)
  if(rect.x~=nil)then  -- checking for its presence    
    print("Object exists. So, remove it...")         
    rect:removeSelf()
  end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("tap",myFunction).
```

Keep Coding.............. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have done it, but implementation relays on Corona SDK internal implementation and can stop working without notice. Looks something like this:

```
function AddDestructor(obj, func)
    obj._isWidget = true;
    if (not obj.originalRemove) then
        obj.originalRemove = obj.removeSelf or (function() end);
        obj.removeSelf = function(self)

            for i = 1, #self.D do
                self.D[i](self);
            end
            self:originalRemove();
        end

        obj.D = {};
    end

    table.insert(obj.D, func);

end
```

and you can use this code like this

```
local group = displsy.newGroup();
local r = display.newRect(group, 0, 0, 300, 300);
AddDestructor(r, function()
    print("Tadaaaa I was called before rect died!");
end);
group:removeSelf();
```